# How to add/remove objects from array with a button toggle?

Tags: jquery

I wrote the following which adds items to an array and I made it so that we cannot add a duplicate object into it, however what I'd like to achieve is to actually add/remove if we click again on an added item:

```
  var countryArray = [];
  var countryName = " ";
  $("#africa, #europe, #asia, #america").on("click", function() {
    countryName = $(this).attr("id");
    countryArray.push(countryName);
    $("span").attr("data-country", $.unique(countryArray.sort()));
  });
```

Comment: Rather than `push`ing every time, you'd just check to see if the county was already in the array, and if so, [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array rather than push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pushing to the array every time, check if the key already exists and if it does, `splice` (remove key) from array.

```js
var countryArray = [];
var countryName = " ";
$("#africa, #europe, #asia, #america").on("click", function() {
    countryName = $(this).attr("id");
    let index = countryArray.indexOf(countryName);
    if (index >= 0) {
        countryArray.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        countryArray.push(countryName);
    }
    console.log(countryArray.sort());
    $("span").attr("data-country", countryArray.sort());
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#africa {
  background: red;
}
#europe {
  background: green;
}
#asia {
  background: blue;
}
#america {
  background: black;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="africa"></div>
<div id="europe"></div>
<div id="asia"></div>
<div id="america"></div>
```

Comment: That was the trick `let index = countryArray.indexOf(countryName);` as I wasn't using the index when using `splice`, thanks will accept

Answer (score 1):

```
var countryArray = [];
var countryName = " ";
$("#africa, #europe, #asia, #america").on("click", function() {
  countryName = $(this).attr("id");

  let itemPos = countryArray.indexOf(countryName);
  if (itemPos < 0)
    countryArray.push(countryName);
  else 
    countryArray.splice(itemPos, 1)
  $("span").attr("data-country", $.unique(countryArray.sort()));
});
```

Comment: That was the trick `let index = countryArray.indexOf(countryName);` as I wasn't using the index when using `splice`, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because **data-country** is a data attribute I would suggest to convert the countryArray to an object.

In this way the code will be:

```js
var countryArray = {};
var countryName = " ";
$("#africa, #europe, #asia, #america").on("click", function() {
    if (countryArray[this.id] === undefined) {
        countryArray[this.id] = true;
    } else {
        delete countryArray[this.id];
    }
    $("span").data("country", countryArray);
    console.log(Object.keys(countryArray).join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="africa">africa</button>
<button id="europe">europe</button>
<button id="asia">asia</button>
<button id="america">america</button>
<span></span>
```

Comment: simple and easy, thanks, why do you suggest to convert it into an object?

Answer (score 0):

By adding `.splice(index, itemsNum)` (to remove an item at index) you can remove the `$.unique`.
By usign a class (instead of ID) you'll have more freedom of IDs

```js
var arr = [];

$(".btn").on("click", function() {

  var i = arr.indexOf(this.id);
  i>-1 ? arr.splice(i, 1) : arr.push(this.id);
  $("span").attr("data-country", arr.sort());
  
});
```

```css
span:after { content: attr(data-country); }
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="africa">africa</button>
<button class="btn" id="europe">europe</button>
<button class="btn" id="asia">asia</button>
<button class="btn" id="america">america</button>
<span data-country=""></span>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```